# Comparison functions for 2D points

Tags: c++, comparative-review, coordinate-system

I have the following class for 2D points:

```
class Point {
private:
    double _x, _y;

public:
    Point(double x, double y) : _x(x), _y(y);

    double x() const { return _x; }
    double y() const { return _y; }
};
```

I wanted to add a few comparison functions that compared objects of this class in different ways.

One of them is just a simple function:

```cpp
/// Returns whether A has a smaller y-coordinate than B
/// (and smaller x-coordinate in case of equality).
bool yComp(const Point &A, const Point &B) {
    if (A.y() != B.y()) return A.y() < B.y();
    return A.x() < B.x();
}
```

The other is a `struct` with `operator()` defined on it:

```cpp
struct angleComp {
    Point origin;
    angleComp(const Point &P);
    bool operator()(const Point &A, const Point &B);
};

// Constructs a new angle comparison with P as origin
angleComp::angleComp(const Point &P) : origin(P) {}

// Compares according to the angles that the lines joining each point
// to a given origin form with the x-axis.
bool angleComp::operator()(const Point &A, const Point &B) {
    GeometricVector u = A - origin, v = B - origin;
    return u.x()*u.x()*u.sqrNorm() < v.x()*v.x()*v.sqrNorm();
}
```

Do I put the comparisons inside the class definition? The first function could be made a static method, but the problem is I can't put `angleComp` inside the class (as a static member) since one of its fields is of type `Point` itself, which would be an incomplete type (inside the class declaration). And I would prefer these comparison functions to be grouped together (instead of one being a static member, and the other being a top-level thing).

So, an alternative would be to put both outside the class, but to retain some grouping, putting all of them in a `namespace`:

```
namespace PointComp {
    bool yComp(const Point &A, const Point &B);

    struct angleComp {
        Point origin;
        angleComp(const Point &P);
        bool operator()(const Point &A, const Point &B);
    };
}
```

Comment: The code is about 2D points. On Code Review, we mainly classify questions according to the task accomplished by the code rather than by your primary concern about the code, because feedback on any aspect of the code is fair game for answers.

Comment: No, Code Review reviews concrete code. Answers will suggest better practices, but asking for best practices in general is both off-topic and redundant.

Comment: Answers will talk about whether how well your code follows best practices and patterns. Questions should not ask about best practices and design patterns, since they are implicit topics for every review. Also, if your question is specifically about a best practice or design pattern (and not a general critique of your code), then it should go on [softwareengineering.se] instead.

Comment: It's easy to misread the page like that, I agree. But that's not what it says. 200 is absolutely correct here.

Comment: Does the code provided work and are you sure you want a review on it instead of finding out the answer to your original question?

Comment: Feel free to make a suggestion on our [Meta site](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com) if you have a suggestion on how to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Mast I have tried to edit the question to clean the products of my previous misunderstandings about the site, and salvage it into a real CR question. Is it suitable for reopening now? If not, what should I change? (By the way, I did follow your suggestion of [posting on Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9114/proposal-to-clarify-on-topic-help-page))

Comment: Do you think the comments by @200 are fully addressed? Because I have my doubts about it. I strongly advice against further touching this question since it got answered and for you to post improved code, if you can fit it within the scope of CR as outlined in the [help/on-topic], as a *new* question.

Comment: @Mast Yes, I specifically tried to fix the matters addressed in 200's comments, to the best of my ability. **I'm not posting improved code**, I'm just putting in what I had before the question got answered in a format suitable for CR, without skipping over details, and without hypothetical or incomplete code. And without asking for "best practices". If you read it in its last revision, without knowledge of its past history, it is an on-topic question for CR, right? Otherwise, what else can I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overall design seems a bit complicated to me. Setters and getters are often more of an hindrance than a real asset, and the benefits of having a simple `struct` should not be under-estimated. In particular, it reminds you that you don't have to encapsulate everything, and that defining functions at the point of use is often the most convenient way to proceed:

```
struct Point { float x, y; };

// ...

// here I need to compare points by y and then x
auto best = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto point_a, auto point_b) {
    return std::tie(point_a.y, point_a.x) < std::tie(point_b.y, point_b.x);
    //      -> tie gives you the lexicographic comparison for free
});

// and there by angle with etc.
auto widest = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [origin](auto point_a, auto point_b) {
    // ...
});
```

In a nutshell, why having a `namespace` and custom classes where you can simply use a lambda?